# php json_decode loop through unique only

Tags: php, json

I recieve this json formatted data as string to my php code:

```
  $json_str = {{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }
}
```

This is the loop:

```
$emp = $_POST["emp"]; //this is the json str
$emp_arr = json_decode($emp);
foreach($emp_arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr 
       $fname= $item->firstName; //etc 
       $lname= $item->lastName; //etc 
      //saving to DB line
    }
```

after I convert it to php array using: json_decode($json_str) I loop through it and write these values to DB.
The problem is, that it writes "John Doe" only once. Is there something that prevents duplicate values in that kind of loop, or perhaps I should decode it differently?
I need this value twice in my DB.

Thank You.

Comment: Please show the decoded result you get!

Comment: There are too many possibilities, and without showing your code we can't help. Can you please show your `iteration` and `insertion` ?

Comment: Just test if the value exist in your DB before your insert

Comment: Please show the complete code and the schema for the table you write the data to.

Comment: The value of `$json_str` is not a string in your example. It's actually nothing. The code you posted is invalid PHP, so there is not much we can say about it. Even if it was a string (somehow) it would be invalid JSON.

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** if you want to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your json object. This code works:

```php
  $json_str = '[
{"firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" } , 
{"firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" } , 
{"firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }
] ';


$emp_arr = json_decode($json_str);
foreach($emp_arr as $item) { //foreach element in $arr 
     echo   $fname= $item->firstName; //etc 
   echo    $lname= $item->lastName; //etc 
      //saving to DB line
    }
```

See the [demo](http://codepad.org/d0siCiaQ).

Answer (score 0):

Your `json` is not valid.

Try with this `json` string.

```
    <?php
$json_str = '[{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" },{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }]';   

$array = json_decode($json_str, true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>";

 for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++)
 {
   $name=$array[$i]['firstName']." ".$array[$i]['lastName'];
   $sql="INSERT INTO yourTable (nameField) VALUES ('$name')";
   //DB Query
 }
?>
```

You can loop through `$array` to insert your data.

Solution First suggested by the user @Roopendra. Later He removed answer.